# El carácter de declaración de tipo no coincide con el tipo de datos declarado

Tags: vba

Buenos dias tengo este codigo en visual basic access :

```
Dim nom As String
Dim nro As String
nom = nombre
nro = (nro_identificacion)
MsgBox (nro)
intx = DCount("*", "[historial]", "[nro_identificacion]= " & nro&)
```

y en la linea intx me da el error (El carácter de declaración de tipo no coincide con el tipo de datos declarado) 
El campo nro_identificacion es texto de 20 caracteres y la quiero comparar con la variable nro tipo string. tomo el dato de la tabla 1 y la busco en la tabla 2 con el mismo campo en las 2.
no encuentro la solucion a esto por favor quier pueda prestarme ayuda lo agradeceria...

Comment: no sobra un & al final?

Comment: Lo elimine y  ahora me da error  2471 (la expresion que ha especificado  como parametro de la consulta produjo el error x)

Comment: Y ese error lo buscaste? que es error x? por favor, actualiza tu pregunta.

Comment: Ese es simplemente el contenido de la variable nro

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask]. Por favor aclara tu pregunta.

Comment: intx = DCount("*", "[historial]", "[nro_identificacion]= " & nro&)  esta instruccion deberia contar en la tabla historial todos los registros que contengan el valor nro pero no logro colocar la sintaxis correcta o estoy usando mal la variable me da error (el caracter de declaracion de tipo no coincide con el tipo de dato declarado) o me da error 1471 en tiempo de ejecucion.. Gracias por tu ayuda..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno tenes dos errores mas que sustanciales.

Primero el & al final de la instruccion no tiene ningun sentido. & se usa para concatenar variables. En este caso, despues de nro no se para que lo estas usando...

O en realidad si se para que,

El problema es que copiaste este codigo, y no entendiste lo que estabas copiando. Si nro_identificacion es un campo de tipo string, entonces la consulta para ese campo debe ser en un campo rodeado con comillas simples `'`

entonces tu instrucción deberia ser:

```
intx = DCount("*", "[historial]", "[nro_identificacion]= '" & nro & "'")
```